# Auto-fill the current date if the previous row was empty

Tags: date, excel, excel-2007, autofill, vba

I have a spreadsheet sorted by dates. Everyday, I enter new data into it. After each day, I leave one row empty before starting the next day. Example:

```
20.09.12 XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXX
         XXXXX XXXX  XXXXX XX
         XX    XXXXX XX    XXXX

21.09.12 XXX   XXXXX XXX   XXXX
         X     XXXX  XXXX  XXX

22.09.12 XXXX  XX    XXXX  XXXX
```

So I want excel to always fill in the current date whenever I enter data after one blank row, but obviously the dates shall stay the same - not be updated to the current date whenever I open excel. I am using Excel 2007 and while non vba ideas are preferred, vba is not a problem either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple (crude?) way of doing it with VBA using the `Worksheet_Change` event of a worksheet.

Effectively, each time you change a cell it checks to see if the entire row above is blank and, if so, puts today's date in column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(Target.Offset(-1, 0).Row)) = 0 Then
        Range("A" & Target.Row) = Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yy")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea, but to make it work, drop the `Selection.` out of `CountA(Selection. ...)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a shortcut for inserting today's date: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>
I think if you use the shortcut, you probably don't need a macro.

Similar shortcut for time is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: + 1 for a non VBA Solution :) BTW Glad to see you here ;)